# In Emacs, can we make one keystroke to do different command?

Tags: emacs

I want to make one keystroke, say `C-F12`, to do `delete-other-windows` or `winner-undo`. I think it's easy if I already learning Emacs Lisp programming, and set a boolean flag. That is, if previously it run `delete-other-window`, now it'll run `winner-undo`.

How do you do that in Emacs Lisp?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
(setq c-f12-winner-undo t)

(define-key (current-global-map) [C-f12]
  (lambda() 
    (interactive) 
    (if c-f12-winner-undo 
        (winner-undo)
      (delete-other-windows))
    (setq c-f12-winner-undo (not c-f12-winner-undo))))
```

Comment: awesome! Well, I try to understand that code.  Hm,.. it's rather the same like any other programming language. I guess the first code is preparing the boolean flag. (I dunno what is lambda()), interactive. and there you have `if c-f12-winner-undo`.. and the rest ^_^

Thanks @oleg!

Comment: Btw, It feels very strange, when a text editor can be programmed, and not just make customization file. ..:)

Comment: lambda is an anonymous function. Just in a case you don't want to give names to all small functions which are used locally. interactive is necessary to be able to call this function interactively (via C-f12). Everything else is straightforward. Yes, I love Emacs because I can program it as I want

Comment: aah, ok, lambda. I am preparing the material needed to learn Emacs Lisp. That should give me some right direction in using emacs. Any good references that you can give? thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest the following tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun swdev-toggle-sole-window ()
  (interactive)
  (if (cdr (window-list))
      (delete-other-windows)
    (winner-undo)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f12>") 'swdev-toggle-sole-window)
```

1. The first line starts the declaration of a function called `swdev-toggle-sole-window`, taking no argument.
2. This function is declared as interactive, i.e. it can be called with `M-x` or through a key binding.
3. If the window list contains more than one element, i.e. if there is more than one window, …
4. … then delete other windows …
5. … else undo the window deletion.
6. Bind the function to the key `C-f12`.

Comment: not quite what I expected :) 
I thought of doing `delete-other-windows` if the window is not maximized. And if it's maximized, it will do `winner-undo`.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the approach taken by Emacs' recenter-top-bottom function:

```
(defun delete-other-window-or-winner-undo ()
  "call delete-other-window on first invocation and winner-undo on subsequent invocations"
  (interactive)
  (if (eq this-command last-command) 
      (winner-undo)
    (delete-other-windows)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f12>") 'delete-other-window-or-winner-undo)
```

Comment: same as above :)
I dunno, maybe the behaviour of `winner-undo` indeed like that. Actually, what I am aiming is, for `f12` to maximized window if it's not maximized, and do `winner-undo` if it's maximized. I am trying by the way :)